# Warning: Built-in CSS support is being disabled due to custom CSS configuration being detected

Tags: next.js

I am trying to `import "../../node_modules/react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";` in my next.js project but I get following error

```
[ error ] ./node_modules/react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Please move all global CSS imports to pages/_app.js.
Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/css-global
Location: components\crud\BlogCreate.js
```

I managed to make it work with next.config.js. It worked with this configuration

```
// next.config.js 
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withCSS({
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    url: false
  }
});
```

But now I am getting a warning,

```
Warning: Built-in CSS support is being disabled due to custom CSS configuration being detected.
See here for more info: https://err.sh/next.js/built-in-css-disabled
```

It seems my solution is not the best way to solve this problem. How could I get rid of this warning?

Comment: It depends what you want to do. Is it a global CSS or for one page / component?

Comment: Its for one component now. Maybe later it will be for all component related with this component @NikolaiKiselev

Comment: And one thing more thing which is really strange, while I posting this thread my project working except the warning. But after add some functionality I can't access the route. It didn't show any error but just loading. When I remove those functionality although same problem happening. I can't go the previous stage.

Comment: I've tried to explain most common cases. Next.js doesn't support importing CSS in components unless it's a `CSS Module`. If you still need to import CSS on a component level you can use a custom loader, like you did `@zeit/next-css` or use a regular `<link>` in the render.

Answer (score 6):

You may remove the `@zeit/next-css` plugin because the Next.js 9.3 is very simple. Then Next.js 9.3 is [**Built-in Sass Support for Global Stylesheets**](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#built-in-sass-support-for-global-stylesheets) after removing the `@zeit/next-css` you may install

```
npm install sass
```

Then, import the Sass file within `pages/_app.js`.

Comment: Thanks for that. In my case, I just remove `@zeit/next-css` and it works. I didn't have to install `sass` because I use a pure CSS file. Tanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't have any sass file to import @fool-dev. My main purpose is to import "../../node_modules/react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css" into my component1.js(component). But I didn't get how to use it with pages/_app.js ? Suppose in pages/_app.js I import import "../../node_modules/react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css" then how to pass my component1.js to _app.js as child or wrapper compoent to get that style?

Comment: @NajmunNahar That's fine you don't need to install sass but you have to remove other zeit plugins like css

Answer (score 1):

### Global CSS

Import any global CSS in the `/pages/_app.js`.

```
import '../styles.css'

// This default export is required in a new `pages/_app.js` file.
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

***Importing CSS in components or pages won't work with the built-in CSS support.***

### Component CSS

Next.js supports CSS Modules using the `[name].module.css` file naming convention.

*components/Button.module.css*

```
/*
You do not need to worry about .error {} colliding with any other `.css` or
`.module.css` files!
*/
.error {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
```

*components/Button.js*

```
import styles from './Button.module.css'

export function Button() {
    return (
        <button
            type="button"
            // Note how the "error" class is accessed as a property on the imported
            // `styles` object.
            className={styles.error}
        >
            Destroy
        </button>
    )
}
```

**CSS Module files can be imported anywhere in your application.**

### Third-party CSS on Component / Page level

You can use `<link>` tag in the component.

```
const Foo = () => (
    <div>
        <link 
            href="third.party.css" 
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
    </div>
);

export default Foo;
```

The loaded stylesheet won't be automatically minified as it doesn't go through build process, so use the minified version.

If none of the options doesn't fit your requirements consider using a custom CSS loader like [@zeit/next-css](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css).

In that case you will see a warning which is fine:

```
Warning: Built-in CSS support is being disabled due to custom CSS configuration being detected.
See here for more info: https://err.sh/next.js/built-in-css-disabled
```

Suggested reading:

- [Next.js Built-In CSS Support](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support)
- [Global SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60914828/next-js-9-import-third-party-plugin-css/60945088#60945088)
- [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)

Answer (score 0):

1. Install sass module by running following command.

```
npm install sass
```

2. You then need to remove all css-loader and sass-loader configuration from next.config.js.

For example, I had to remove the `withSass()` function (in your case `withCSS()`) and just return the configuration object.
Had to remove the following lines from next.config.js

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: {
    loader: "sass-loader",
    options: {
      data: '@import "./scss/_variables.scss"',
      sourceMap: true,
    },
  },
}
```

Move your options to sassOptions in next config file.

```
sassOptions: {
  data: '@import "./scss/_variables.scss"',
  sourceMap: true,
}
```

3. Also remove the old @zeit/next-sass and @zeit/next-css from package.json

I had to remove following @zeit dependency from my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-sass": "1.0.1",
```

This worked for me.

For more details, visit https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support